# Nested GroupBy extension method in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can someone show me a a simple example of a nested GroupBy extension method.  I am trying to group an object into a list. I figure it will look something like this:

//Code

```
List<stats> myStats = GetStatsList().GroupBy( d => d.date).GroupBy(t => t.team)
        Select(s => new stats
  {
        Date = 
        Team = 
 }).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
    List<stats> myStats = GetStatsList()
                            .GroupBy(s => new { s.date, s.team })
                            .Select(g => new stats { Date = g.Key.date , Team = g.Key.team})
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: The AsEnumerable() is superfluous. .Select() already produces an Enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want this:

```
List<stats> myStats = GetStatsList()
    .GroupBy(s => new{ s.Date, s.Team})
    .Select(g => new stats
      {
            Date = g.Key.Date,
            Team = g.Key.Team,
     }).ToList();
```

I'm grouping by an anonymous type with the two properties you want to use in different `GroupBy`s. Then i can access them via `Group.Key.PropertyName`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myStats = (from s in GetStatsList()
               group by new { Date = s.date, Team = s.team} into g
               select g.Key).ToList();
```

Note that this gives you a `List<T>` where T is an anonymous type -- that might be sufficient. If you explicitly need a List then:

```
var myStats = (from s in GetStatsList()
               group by new { s.date, s.team} into g
               select new stat { Date = g.Key.date, Team = g.Key.team}).ToList();
```